# Get tag using text selenium beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I know there's a way using xpath and javascript

```
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'text')]")
```

but this method doesn't detect elements/tags, that are defined just as tags, eg:

```
    <p>
      <span class="text-primary">UK</span>
      +44 (0) 1865 987 667<br>
      Piccadilly Gardens, 49 Piccadilly, Manchester, M1 2AP </p>
```

In this case, if the text is **+44 (0) 1865 987**,it does not get the element.

1. This issue is repetitive in many examples, that incorporates the text this way. What could be the reason?
2. Is there a way to get the tag, searching using text, in **beautifulsoup**?

Comment: Can there be more than one occurrence within the html?

Comment: @QHarr yes. There can be. I found a solution by searching for all the tags using selenium, and then matching with the call string. I included **a** and **p** for the tags. However, it can get generic than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that you need to use the following functions combination:

1. [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) - to look for matches in children/ignore leading/trailing whitespaces, etc.
2. [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) - for the partial match

Putting everything together:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(normalize-space(),'+44 (0) 1865 987 667')]")
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium you can try with `Sub string` matching.

```
text="+44 (0) 1865 987 667"
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(.,'" + text + "')]"))).text)
```